# background image repeating on some pages despite having same coding for all

Tags: html, css, image

Most likely a css problem, the images I'm using as backgrounds for each page are repeating & varying in size. The homepage is the only completely functional section.
Here's a live example: http://athenatestingwebsite.tumblr.com/
And here's my html:

```
<div id="PROJECTSP">
<a id="projects" class="smooth"></a>
</div>

<div id="CONTACTP">
<a id="contact" class="smooth"></a>
</div>
```

and here's some of my css:

```
body {
height: 1000px;
}

#projectsp  {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0a0b38;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/rrmPP7E.png");
}

#contactp  {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0a0b38;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/s9gGzHO.png");
}
```

Comment: Css are case sensitive

Comment: @AlvaroJoao thank you! I'm a complete beginner so information like that is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
 background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
```

add this line after every background image you set. remove 
body height,width remove all #id height 1000px or 2000px you set..set height auto.

add this class

```
      div.slogan h1 {
      margin: auto;
         }
```

hope all will be fix. without the nav overlay. 
[image]

Happy Coding . Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately, this happened after I inserted your coding! http://i.imgur.com/jx4PHXL.png, http://i.imgur.com/AV3jSM8.png ): and here's a live example: http://athenatestingwebsite.tumblr.com/

Comment: your first mistake you dont set ' ; ' at the end  background
 #aboutp {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #0a0b38;
    display: inline-block;
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/pncSrCe.png"); 
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
}

Comment: ah, thank you! I just fixed that and one of the backgrounds moved back into its position.

Comment: you missed to close 2 div end <div id="homep">  <div id="projectsp"> 
and do you want to the "homep" background image as a full page background image ??

Comment: ah! thank you again, sorry about small mistakes like that, I'm a complete beginner so I miss them as I read over my code! And yes, I want them all as full page background images. Thank you!

Comment: so each section have 1 background image.

Comment: yes, I've just fixed the divs and added the missing ";". Each page is intended to have a different background. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: you will face some issue. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixsssdr3sfmjjda/changes%28tumb%29.txt?dl=0] download and look where i have changes. and you don't need the background-repeat-y: no-repeat; because you have close all the div. 
and you told me you are beginner so learn bootstrap  [http://getbootstrap.com/]